# Can not get expo push token

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building a React native app which is based on Expo , i use Expo's push notification . when i test app with expo cli i get the expo token . and after i generate a .aab and i post it on play store . i can't get the expo token from any device . i don't know why .

```
registerForPushNotification = async() => {
    // Check for existing permissions
    const {status} = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    let finalStatus = status;

    // if no existing permission, ask user for permission
    if (status !== 'granted') {
        const {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        finalStatus = status;
    }

    // if no permission, exit the function.
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!')
      return;}

    // get push notification token.
    let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
    alert(token)
    firebase.database().ref('/users/usersInfo/'+user).update({
      expoToken:token
    })

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      Notifications.createChannelAndroidAsync('default', {
        name: 'default',
        sound: true ,
        priority: 'max',
        vibrate: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I had this problem where the "Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()" function never resolved the promise. I have since upgraded to SDK 38 with the hopes that their new notification API will sort this however now the updated function throws an error - https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9061

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use push notifications for your app, your should register the app for firebase.

If you have not already created a Firebase project for your app, do so now by clicking on **Add project** in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).

In your new project console, click **Add Firebase to your Android app** and follow the setup steps. **Make sure that the Android package name you enter is the same as the value of** `android.package` **in your** `app.json`.

Download the `google-services.json` file and place it in your Expo app's root directory.

In your `app.json`, add an `android.googleServicesFile` field with the relative path to the `google-services.json` file you just downloaded. If you placed it in the root directory, this will probably look like:

```
{
  ...
  "android": {
    "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
    ...
  }
}
```

Now you can build your standalone app by using `expo build:android -t apk` or the app bundle `expo build:android -t app-bundle`

> from the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/).

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I follow your instruction.

Comment: Once you have created your project on firebase you may also need to upload your server key to expo so they can trigger the notifications. Follow the instructions here https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/using-fcm/